# Last click attribution/greatest n per user in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to select the last campaign a user clicked in my dataset and return a table with the name of the last clicked campaign and date for each anonymous id.

This is what I have written

```
select  anon,
           source,
           medium,
           campaign,
           max(ts) as ts
           from attribution
group by 1,2,3,4
```

This code seems to return the last click date, but in cases where the user clicked on two campaigns it will return both campaigns with the latest date appended to the date column.

TS in this scenario refers to the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        anon,
        source,
        medium,
        campaign,
        ts,
        row_number() over(partition by anon order by ts desc) rn
    from attribution
) where rn = 1
```

This assumes that `anom` is the column that hold the username - if that's not the case, then change it to the relevant column in the `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)` clause.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but wouldn't this return the first click associated with a user?

Comment: @Emm: the `over` clause orders records by *descending*  `ts`, so the record with `rn = 1` is the latest.